# gradle kotlin-dsl move android {} into subproject {} in root project build.gradle.kts

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to move `android {}` (individual module) into `subprojects {}` (root project `build.gradle.kts`) (to avoid duplicate of same `android {}` in every module)

I was able to move when using gradle `groovy`. but in gradle `kotlin-dsl`. it seems impossible to reference `android` in `subprojects {}`

I have tried

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
       if (project.plugins.hasPlugin(Plugins.kotlinAndroidApplication)) {
          project.android {

       }
    }
}
```

But always getting this error: `Unresolved reference: android`

Is there any way to access `android {}` inside `subprojects {}` for `kotlin-dsl`?

Comment: Hi  Lê Khánh Vinh. Are you seeing the edits on your prior questions? You should be receiving notifications for each one.

Answer (score 2):

try this way:

```
subprojects {
    project.plugins.configure(project)
}

fun PluginContainer.configure(project: Project) {
    whenPluginAdded {
        if (this is AndroidBasePlugin) {
            project.extensions
                .getByType<BaseExtension>()
                .apply {
                    applyAndroidCommons()
                }
        }
    }
}

fun BaseExtension.applyAndroidCommons() {
    compileSdkVersion(BuildConfig.COMPILE_SDK)

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(BuildConfig.MIN_SDK)
        targetSdkVersion(BuildConfig.TARGET_SDK)
    }

    // other stuff you would put into android{}
}
```